# Rearranged vector elements after std::unique

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm currently working through Stanley Lippman's C++ Primer. In Chapter 10 generic algorithms are introduced.

As an example `std::sort`, `std::unique` and the `std::vector` member function `erase` shall be used to remove duplicate elements within a vector.

To see how a vectors elements are rearranged by std::unique I tried to print every element just to find that not all elements are printed. However a call to `.size()` tells that the size of the vector is as expected unchanged.

After compiling the program:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -o elimDubs elimDubs.cc
```

and calling the programm with

```
./elimDubs the quick red fox jumps over the slow red turtle
```

The program prints

```
Size after std::unique: 10
fox jumps over quick red slow the turtle the
```

which are only 9 of the 10 elements. (`red` is missing)
Why? For the program it doesn't really matter as the subsequent call of `erase` is used to remove the duplicate elements anyways, still it irritates me that there are elements missing or at least not being printed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void elimDubs( std::vector<std::string> &words )
{
  std::sort( words.begin(), words.end() );

  auto end_unique = std::unique( words.begin(), words.end() );


  std::cout << "Size after std::unique: "
            << words.size() << std::endl;

  for ( const auto &el : words )
    std::cout << el << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::vector<std::string> sentence;

  if ( argc < 2 )
    return -1;

  std::copy( argv + 1, argv + argc,
             std::back_inserter(sentence) );

  elimDubs( sentence );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `sentence` can be initialized directly with `std::vector<std::string> sentence(argv + 1, argv + argc);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique` is a destructive process.  Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique),

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten.

This means that any elements after the new end iterator returned by `std::unique` are going to be in a valid but unspecified state.  They aren't meant to be accessed as they should be removed from the vector with a call to `erase`.

This is also noted in the note section:

> Iterators in `[r, last)` (if any), where `r` is the return value, are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values. A call to `unique` is typically followed by a call to a container's `erase` member function, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

Comment: Good answer, this is known as the "erase-remove idiom" and is so common it gets it's own Wikipedia entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Answer (score 1):

There's still 10 elements; it's just that one of them is "moved from". If you change your print loop to quote the words, thus:

```
  for ( const auto &el : words )
    std::cout << "'" << el << "'" << " ";
```

you'll see the following output:

```
'fox' 'jumps' 'over' 'quick' 'red' 'slow' 'the' 'turtle' 'the' ''
```